# PHP MySQL show related items using tags

Tags: php, mysql, tags, match, against

I want to show similar items using tags.

I have items table with `itemid`, `itemname` and `itemtagids` as columns. `itemtagids` has CSV tag ids.

Say in `itemid 1`, I have 3 tag ids `1,2,3` and in `itemid 2` I have 4 tag ids `3,4,5,6` in `itemid 3` I have 2 tag ids `2,3` and so on..

I want that for `itemid 1` in similar items 3rd `itemid` should be shown first (because it has 2 matching) then `itemid 2` and so on..

What i have used is:

```
SELECT itemid 
FROM items 
WHERE MATCH (itemtagids ) AGAINST ('2823' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

it does return results only in the case when there is one `itemtagid` in `itemtags` ids column.

sequence is something lie: `234,546,2823,342,5643` So, here 2823 is not an individual word but a complete string from 234,54...43

what should be done in this case where tags are in the form of ids and in CSV format.

Comment: Are you using Many-2-Many Relationships ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a FULLTEXT isn't the right search for your case. Try using regular expressions instead.

```
SELECT `itemid`
FROM `items`
WHERE `itemtagids` REGEXP '^2823$' 
OE `itemtagids` REGEXP '^2823,'
OR `itemtagids` REGEXP ',2823$'
OR `itemtagids` REGEXP ',2823,';
```

EDIT: or perhaps you might do with a single regular expression, like:

```
SELECT `itemid`
FROM `items`
WHERE `itemtagids` REGEXP '[[:<:]]2823[[:>:]]';
```

Hope it helps!